# Foreign keys cause more queries?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have 2 objects - Order and Product. On the Order only productID is saved and when I view orders I want to see the product name. According to ScuttGu blog this is easily done by using a template field with Eval("Product.ProductName"). However, when reviewing the actual queries I see that for each order a separate query is made.

It doesn't sould right to me because for many rows and/or foreign keys many additional queries will be made. Doesn't it make the whole this too inefficient (i.e. why linq doesn't use a join)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is because your products are lazy loaded - that is they are loaded when needed.

You can DataLoadOptions to set your fetchingstrategy, and load the products with your order:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
options.LoadWith<Order>(order => order.Product);
db.LoadOptions = options;
var orders = from c in db.Orders
```

If you don't like the pr. datacontext specification of loadoptions you do something like this (not testet):

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
db.Orders
    .Select(o => new { Order = o, Products = o.Products})
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => x.Order)
    .ToList();
```

I have implemented something like [this guys fethingstrategies](http://www.simonsegal.net/blog/2008/07/15/linq-to-sql-dynamic-querying-fetching-strategies-cont/), which works out nicely with my repositories and the specification pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because at the point that Eval has run, the query already has, without said join.

When you're fetching the query you can use [DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx) to include this using the [`.LoadWith()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.loadwith.aspx):

```
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Order>(o => o.Product);
var dc = new DataContext();
dc.LoadOptions = dlo;

var orders = from dc.Orders select o;
```